# A problem on curves of genus 3

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $Y_0$ be a smooth projective complex curve of genus two
and $Y_1\to Y_0$ a non trivial etale map of degree two
(so $Y_1$ has genus three, and it is hyperelliptic). Call $\sigma$ the involution of
$Y_1$ over $Y_0$ and let $J_1$ be the jacobian of $Y_1$.
Consider the map $f:Y_1\to J_1$ mapping $P$ to
$\sigma(P)-P$ and the multiplication by two $g:J_1\to J_1$.
Let $Y_2$ be a connected component of the fiber product
of $f$ and $g$, and $d$ the degree of $Y_2$ over $Y_1$.

Question : $Y_0$ being given, what is the minimal value of
$d$?